# How to pass Bitmap through bundle and receive the same bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

In my app there is a module in which the user has to take multiple pictures. After capturing the image i am converting the imageURI to bitmap and placing that bitmap to the ImageView.
The app works fine in all the devices except in Samsung. 
In order to fix this issue i have to pass the bitmap to `onSaveInstanceState` method and receive that bitmap in `onCreate` method. For doing this i have pass the bitmap to Bundle but i am unable to pass the bitmap through bundle.
Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitmap class implements Parceable Interface So you can save it in bundle as .

```
saveInstance.putParcelable("bm", yourBitmap);
```

and recieve it as

```
Bitmap bm = savedInstance.getParcelable("bm");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. Saved me lot of time.